# storing a hash password

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, hash, sha256

i would like to hash a varchar and store it in db but i 've got a problem
when checking its value ,i thought i just had to hash it again and compare to db value

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddLecteur]
                @userName NVARCHAR(50), 
                @PasswordHash NVARCHAR(50),

                @biblioPrincip int  

            AS
            BEGIN
               SET NOCOUNT ON
        declare @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(250)
        declare @salt varbinary(4)=crypt_gen_random(4)
        BEGIN TRY

            INSERT INTO lecteur(nom, motPassword, biblioPrincipal)
            VALUES(@userName,HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',cast( @PasswordHash as varbinary(max))+@salt),  @biblioPrincip)

            SET @ErrorMessage='Success'

        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            SET @ErrorMessage=ERROR_MESSAGE() 
        END CATCH

            END
```

the value inserted is ‰¥_#ç¢¿K¤IFÕšxHà6œûäÜô4îõ„R¨Ó
        am i not supposed to get the same value when checking the user if i use a salt inserted at the creation of the user and hash the user input the same way?
        the second trigger hashing a proposal to compare to the one above generated when creating the user

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckngUser]
    @userName varchar(50),
    @password nvarchar(50),
    @libelle varchar(50)


    AS
    BEGIN

    declare @salt varbinary(4)
    set @salt=(select lecteur.salt from lecteur where lecteur.nom=@userName)
    select HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',cast( @password as varbinary(max))+@salt), 

    le.id,le.nom,le.[motPassword],bi.libellé from lecteur as le
    inner join biblio as bi on le.biblioPrincipal=bi.id
    where le.nom=@userName and le.motPassword=HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',cast( 

    @password as varbinary(max))+@salt)
    END
```

why do i have this value here  0x7774FB52EB1FB5D3DD731A8B64B4BA1A73F4893F8A3C9084248D774D83C3E326

Comment: That is not a secure choice of password hash.

Comment: are you talking about adding a salt?

Comment: Among other things. For example, SHA-256 is too fast to be suitable for password hashing.

Comment: it's not really in my scope but i ddin't want let the password in my db as varchar

Comment: is it better ? and why don't i have the same value?